# Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation and FluentValidation.MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation, ninject.web.mvc

I have tried setting up Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation in my ASP.NET MVC4 project 
as shown below:

```
var ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel);
//ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel)));
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory);

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

but I am getting the below errors:

```
Error   1   The type 'FluentValidation.ValidatorFactoryBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'FluentValidation, Version=2.0.0.0, ...

Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation.NinjectValidatorFactory' to 'FluentValidation.IValidatorFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I can see the NuGet Package for Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation is version 3.0.0.0
and the error is telling me it is looking for version 2 of FluentValidation for its dependency.

If I install the NuGet package just for Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation then it installs the FluentValidation v2 dependency rather than version 3.4.6

but I can also see here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation/commit/82096d0afd15c41d01c09fd47f4247682261768e
a note about the project being updated for version 3.4.6

I am currently using NuGet to add the FluentValidation.MVC4 package to my project and then adding Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation after it (which finds it's dependency already exists and doesn't add it).

I can see that the NuGet package was last published on the 1st April 2013 but when I look at the .nuspec file in my project it shows

```
<dependency id="FluentValidation" version="3.2.0.0" />
```

Is there anything I have done wrong with this setup? or a way I can get this working through the package manager console to update the dependency version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The reason for this is because `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation` is using the signed version of `FluentValidation` which is strongly named.

David Ebbo has a good post about strong names and binding redirects here
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/nuget-versioning-part-3-unification-via.html

I still did not bother doing this to fix my problem, the NuGet package only has 1 class, the `NinjectValidatorFactory`, so it's worth just implementing your own.

---

To fix my problem for now I have put the `NinjectValidatorFactory`class into my own project. This looks to me like the current NuGet package needs to be updated further before it uses FluentValidation 3.4.6.

Comment: Same here. Do you happen to know the location of the repository for this package?

Comment: THe NinjectValidatorFactory.cs is here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation/tree/master/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation

Answer (score 3):

enter these codes in Package Manager Console :

```
Install-Package FluentValidation-Signed
Install-Package FluentValidation.MVC3-Signed -IgnoreDependencies
Install-Package Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation -IgnoreDependencies
```

-IgnoreDependencies is important .